# C Sort Input By First Value and Second Value Into A Linked List

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list

I have been struggling with this for the past few days. DISCLAIMER: This is for a homework assignment. I have been working on it myself but I can't really figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

I am given a list of airline flight baggage info in the format Airline, Destination, Baggage Car Number.

I have to sort this list into a new list. The new list has to be sorted by Airline and within each airline it has to be sorted by destination.

- Singapore Baltimore 176
- ATA Allentown 1549
- Continental Bridgeport 915
- Singapore Berkeley 878
- Singapore Livonia 1462
- Quantas Fremont 1610

Would sort out to:

- ATA Allentown 1549
- Continental Bridgeport 915
- Quantas Fremont 1610
- Singapore Baltimore 176
- Singapore Berkeley 878
- Singapore Livonia 1462

Here is what I am working with right now:

```
#Main.cpp#
int main()
{
    Node * head = NULL;

    ifstream fin("planes.txt");
    string airline, destination;
    int carNum;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin >> airline >> destination >> carNum;
        insertNode(airline, destination, carNum, head);
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



#Node.cpp#
void insertNode(string value1, string value2, int value3, Node *&head)
{
    Node * ptr = head;
    if (ptr == NULL || ptr->getString1() > value1)
    {
        insertAtHead(value1, value2, value3, head);
    }
    else
    {
        while (ptr->getNext() != NULL && ptr->getNext()->getString1() < value1)
        {
            ptr = ptr->getNext(); // advance to next node in list
        }
        insertValue(value1, value2, value3, ptr);
    }
}

void insertValue (string value1, string value2, int value,Node *afterMe)
{
    afterMe->setNext(new Node(value1, value2, value, afterMe->getNext()));
}

void insertAtHead (string value1, string value2, int value3,Node *&head)
{
    head = new Node(value1, value2, value3, head);
}
```

I am going to leave out my node.h as it only holds function declarations and simeple accessor functions.

My current insertNode function sorts only by the first value. This is one variation of my insertNode function where I try to start sorting by both the first and second value.

It is rather ugly. I am stuck at all of this mess even after several pages of working things out on notebook paper.

```
void insertNode(string value1, string value2, int value3, Node *&head)
{
    Node * ptr = head;
    if (ptr == NULL || ptr->getString1() > value1)
    {
        insertAtHead(value1, value2, value3, head);
    }
    else
    {
        while (ptr->getNext() != NULL)  //Keep going as long as I am not at the end of the list
        {
            if (ptr->getNext()->getString1() < value1) //If Airline in list is smaller then the Airline I am adding
            {
                ptr = ptr->getNext(); //Move onto the next value in the list
            }
            else if (ptr->getNext()->getString1() == value1) //If Airline in list is equivalent to the Airline I am adding
            {
                if(ptr->getNext()->getString2() < value2)   //The airlines matched up. How do the destinations compare?
                {
                    ptr = ptr->getNext(); //If the destination in the list is less than the one I am adding, move on
                }
                else
                {
                    insertValue(value1, value2, value3, ptr); //If one I am adding is not less than the list, add it here.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                insertValue(value1, value2, value3, ptr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function object or a pointer to a function that compares two nodes.

This will allow one linked list function that can be sorted by passing a comparison function object or pointer to a comparison function.

For an example, see `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your precise requirements, it appears you are over complicating this. If you just create a new string to hold Airline + Destination + Baggage Car and insert that into a sorted list, you'd achieve your data goal.

Is there any reason you must keep your data elements in a list row separate? In other words:

```
string strToBeSorted = strAirline;
strToBeSorted += " ";
strToBeSorted += strDestination;
strToBeSorted += " ";
strToBeSorted += strBaggageCar;
```

Then you insert `strToBeSorted`. This will give you one string that can be string sorted. This makes it a simple case to simply sort all entries. You will be able to know where `strToBeSorted` goes as far as Airlines, Destination, and even Baggage Car goes in what order.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.

I have to read in the info Airline, Dest, Number and then add it to the list, sorting as I go. 

So I read in Singapore - Baltimore and add it to the beginning of my list.

Then I read in ATA - KCI. I see that ATA comes before Singapore so I put ATA at the head of the list and move Singapore down one.

And so on and so forth. I can sort like that but taking the second value into account throws me. I am really lost so I hope I am not reading your question/answer incorrectly.

Comment: I appreciate the elaboration. That helps me out quite a bit.

Though, wouldn't I still only be sorting by the value of the fi...(I was typing out this comment and this is where I had a bit of a *facepalm* moment and then ran to Visual Studio.)

That is a fantastic solution to the problem. Instead of comparing one value and then another with a giant if/else. I just compare one string of values. 

string1 = "Singapore Berkeley"
string2 = "Singapore Baltimore"

Compare the two strings as one whole and sort from there.
Brilliant! Much obliged. Thank you, much.